# Positioning item after -webkit-transform:scale()

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, dock

I'm trying to automate the css settings with jQuery, I have functions like

```
$(".footer").css(foot_css)//pre-defined css object
//AND
$(".footer").hover(function(){
$(this).css("-webkit-transform", "scale(2)"); 
});
```

the footer is set to bottom=0 (with foot_css), but when I scale the footer, it does not stay at bottom=0, some of the text are below the screen, thus unreadable. 
Edit: this also happens for left, the left-bottom corner of the ".footer" class is out of screen.

So how can I "dock" the footer to the bottom? Maybe a better way to scale (than webkit and moz) ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `transform:scale`, it will by default rescale in the middle of your rescaled element. If you want to define the origin of the transformation, simply add in your css: `transform-origin: horizontal vertical;`
For example

```
.myScaledObj{
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
   -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%; 
}
```

This would rescale your object with the origin of the transformation being at the top-middle of it